# Bootstrap input fields squared

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't seem to get my corners rounded on any input field on my HTML form. I've tried changing the CSS stylesheet to this:

```
 * {
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px !important;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px !important;
          border-radius: 4px !important;
  -webkit-border-top: 4px !important;
     -moz-border-top: 4px !important;
          border-top: 4px !important;
  -webkit-border-bottom: 4px !important;
     -moz-border-bottom: 4px !important;
          border-bottom: 4px !important;
}
```

but that made it so you couldn't see the top and bottom lines. I'm copying the code straight from their site and it's just not formatting right. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show your HTML markup please?

Comment: Is bootstrap adding any classes to your input box?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check that you put `form-control` class e.g. `class="form-control"` in your input fields??? like

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name">
```

As I know that was happen when you don't put `form-control` class

Comment: Welcome! But you should know the [basics](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) of bootstrap before starting...

Comment: With all of the "form" confusion, its not exactly straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS below:

```
input, input[type="text"]{
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px ;
    border-radius: 4px ;
    border-width: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```